# Primefaces Multiple Selection Datatable not displaying data

Tags: jsf, checkbox, datatable, primefaces, multi-select

Following the Primefaces datatable example at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf, I've been able to construct a datatable that displays the correct headers and number of rows from my data source. However, no data is displayed; it displays blank cells.

After debugging, I've discovered the problem is because of the following section of code in my DataModel:

```
@Override
public Resource getRowData(String rowKey) {
    List<Resource> resources = (List<Resource>) getWrappedData();

    for(Resource resource : resources) {
        if(resource.getResourceId().equals(rowKey))
            return resource;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The `if(resource.getResourceId().equals(rowKey))` condition evaluates to false, and hence no `Resource` object is returned.

I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong. The relevant sections from my `bean` is shown below:

```
public class NewIncidentWizardBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static Logger logger =  Logger.getLogger(NewIncidentWizardBean.class.getName());

private static Resource[] tmpResources;

static {
    tmpResources = new Resource[12];

    tmpResources[0] = new Resource(new Long(1), ..., new Long(2));
    tmpResources[1] = new Resource(new Long(2), ..., new Long(4));
    tmpResources[2] = new Resource(new Long(3), ..., new Long(10));
    tmpResources[3] = new Resource(new Long(4), ..., new Long(10));
    tmpResources[4] = new Resource(new Long(5), ..., new Long(10));
    tmpResources[5] = new Resource(new Long(6), ..., new Long(10));
    tmpResources[6] = new Resource(new Long(7), ..., new Long(10));
    tmpResources[7] = new Resource(new Long(8), ..., new Long(10));
    tmpResources[8] = new Resource(new Long(9), ..., new Long(10));
    tmpResources[9] = new Resource(new Long(10), ..., new Long(10));
    tmpResources[10] = new Resource(new Long(11), ..., new Long(7));
    tmpResources[11] = new Resource(new Long(12), ..., new Long(90));
}

private List<Resource> resources;
private ResourceDataModel resourcesModel;
private Resource selectedResource;
private Resource[] selectedResources;

public NewIncidentWizardBean() {
    resources = new ArrayList<Resource>();
    for(int i = 0; i < tmpResources.length; i++)
        resources.add(tmpResources[i]);

    resourcesModel = new ResourceDataModel(resources);
}

public Resource getSelectedResource() {
    return selectedResource;
}

public void setSelectedResource(Resource selectedResource) {
    this.selectedResource = selectedResource;
}

public Resource[] getSelectedResources() {
    return selectedResources;
}

public void setSelectedResources(Resource[] selectedResources) {
    this.selectedResources = selectedResources;
}

public Resource getResource() {
    return resource;
}

public void setResource(Resource resource) {
    this.resource = resource;
}

public List<Resource> getResources() {
    return resources;
}

public void setResources(List<Resource> resources) {
    this.resources = resources;
}

public ResourceDataModel getResourcesModel() {
    return resourcesModel;
}
}
```

And the relevant section from my view is:

```
<p:dataTable id="resources" var="resource" value="#{newDisasterWizardBean.resourcesModel}" paginator="true" rows="10"  
             selection="#{newDisasterWizardBean.selectedResources}">  

    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px" />  

    <p:column headerText="Resource Name">  
        #{resource.name}  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Description">  
        #{resource.description}  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Resource Type" >  
        #{resource.type}  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Units Required">  
        #{resource.units}  
    </p:column>  

</p:dataTable>
```

I'm not able to discover what I may be doing wrong, yet. Any assistance will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Could you leave a note which PF version you're using?
Since 3.3 there is a change in lazy loading handling of the data table.
Give it a try with 3.2 then you can see whether you're code works fine.
Additionally I have the rowKey tag defined. I guess you should define it!
For triggering select/unselect you should also define these ajax events:

```
    <p:dataTable id="myid"
        value="#{myvalue}" var="valuevar"
        selection="#{value.valueSelected}"
        rowKey="#{valuevar.onevalue}">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
            process="@this"
            update="@this" />
        <p:ajax event="rowUnselect"
            process="@this"
            update="@this" />
                    ...................
    </p:dataTable>
```

I'm currently stick as well in 3.3.1 with the lazy=true parameter mentioned in PrimeFaces issue [2993](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2993).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I solved my problem by removing the process tag from a commandButton which processes the table data!